# Python: How to migrate a R function that applies SVM function for group by in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, svm

I have a data frame (df) that looks like that:

```
   Value Country ID
1   21   RU    AAAU9001025
2   24   NG    AAAU9001848
3   17   EG    ACLU2799370
4   2    EG    ACLU2799370
5   56   RU    ACLU2799370
```

I am running a SVM classifier for outlier detection on the value, per country, and based on relative small sample (max rows: 5K), and I indicate if it is an outlier in each row. So my output is a data frame with additional logical column that indicates if its an outlier:

```
    Value Country ID    SVM
1   21  RU  AAAU9001025 FALSE
2   24  NG  AAAU9001848 FALSE
3   17  EG  ACLU2799370 FALSE
4   2   EG  ACLU2799370 TRUE
5   56  RU  ACLU2799370 TRUE
6   25  EG  AMFU3022141 FALSE
```

I am using the following code in R:

```
library(e1071)

SVM_f = function(x,limit=5000){
N = min(c(limit,length(x)))
mdl = svm(x[sample(length(x),N)],
nu=0.98, type="one-classification", kernel="polynomial")
predict(mdl,x)
}

res = by(df,df$Country,function(x){
data.frame(x,SVM = SVM_f(x$Value))
})

res = do.call(rbind,res)
```

Now I need to migrate this code to Python - please assist.

Comment: Where is your current attempt to do this translation?

Comment: I currently run a SVC algo on subsets of the data, for each country and then append them together, but its no so efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [Rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) where you can use native python language performed within the R environment, so you could leave the R code as it is above.

Here is a more specific [link](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html).

Comment: Can you be more specific please? because I need to use it in Python env. (Jupyter)

Comment: Instead of jupyter you would use the equivalent in R which is more powerful as you can use almost every language in there. You have to use certain expression marks to start and end a language of your chosen.
If this doesn't work, could you please elaborate why you need jupyter?

Comment: Unfortunately I am obligate to use only Jupyter.

Comment: As I asked: Could you please explain why? What is your final goal?

Comment: My final goal is to indicate for each country what id is anomaly based on SVM classification (unsupervised) of it's value. Understood?

Comment: The question was more like: You have R code to solve that. Why do you need that in python?

Comment: I don't want to sound mean but I think this is a good chance to learn both languages in a rather easy way as the code is not that long. There are some tricky details but I think it is doable.
Is your data confidential? If not, I would try to convert it along the next days. A part of the data would probably be sufficient as long as the code makes sense so I can apply it.
I also have to use python but I like R more, so I would see it as an exercise as well :)

Comment: Thanks, Ben, where should I send you the data? I really appreciate this...

Comment: I assume it is not confidential so you could upload it wherever you want? https://www.google.com/search?q=upload+file&rlz=1C1GCEU_deDE852DE852&oq=upload+file&aqs=chrome..69i57.1416j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 or so :)
No problem, thank me later :)